# How can I select a column named 'date' in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with `SELECT` query in ORACLE SQL. There is a table named 'Battles' with columns 'name' and 'date'. When I try to do:

`SELECT date FROM Battles` -

there is an error: `(936) ORA-00936: missing expression`. I guess the problem is name of column 'date' is similar with datatype name. But how can I deal with it?

Comment: Double quotation marks ""?

Comment: This is why i prefer to start columns with c and tables with t, the conflice with reserved keywords is much lower :)

Comment: Thanks Lalit Kumar B! It works perfectly! It's the first time I'm using ORACLE (I have had a deal only with Postgres before), so it hasn't come into my head:(

Comment: FYI, Even in Postgres you will need to escape reserve word using double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to quote a identifier, Oracle uses the double quotes. Be aware, that this also makes them case sensitive (you said the column is named `date` in lowercase, so):

```
select "date" from Battles;
```

See Quoted Identifiers in the [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm#2684).

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @CodeMind good for you :) can you be more specific, in order to help you we need to know what you have tried and what was the error you got. Other than that, it does work that’s why it was accepted as the answer.

Comment: make sure your calling it using the proper case of the column name along with using the double-quotes (i.e. "DATE" instead of "date")

Answer (score 2):

Yes you guessed it correct. `date` is a [`reserve word`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)  in Oracle (in fact it's a datatype) and you should escape it using double quote `""` like below.

```
SELECT "date" FROM Battles
```

That's the very same reason you should never choose column/table names to be reserve word. Even though almost all the RDBMS provides a way/mechanism to bypass this but it's a never a good practice.